# How do I persist query parameters between states?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How do I persist query parameters through each state? For example, let's say a user tries to access to link, but needs to login first before they could get back to that page, so how can I route the user back to the page as well as keep all the query parameters? I spent a few hours trying to figure this out, but couldn't get it to work.

I have looked briefly into UrlMatcher and am unclear if that is what I need given that the documentation is lacking. I tried passing the url params with transitionTo which isn't a great solution because I would have to duplicate support across all states.

Comment: all the state change events have following arguments  `function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ ... })` . Create a simple service to track them when user gets redirected to login

Answer (score 1):

You can get the data of both states like this.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParameters, fromState, fromParameters) {

//You can also see the complete url of the previous state.
console.log(fromState.url);

})
```

with both parameters and url of the starting state I think you can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

i think you may use the state inheritance, specify an abstact root state, config some share data, or you can use it to store query params, see [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#inherited-custom-data)